# Routing issue for the simple post api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, action, routeconfig

I have a action in controller which is returning a class which hold only a message like

```
public Result UpdateTestCaseExecution(string appSecret, string appKey)
        {
            Result result = new Result();

            try.....
        }
```

problem is in routing this is the route i've made but its not getting hit

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "UpdateTestCaseExecution",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{appsecret}/{appkey}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Dynamic", action = "UpdateTestCaseExecution", appsecret = UrlParameter.Optional, appkey = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
```

Comment: if your route `appSecret` and `appKey` is optional then you can set using `[Route("Dynamic/UpdateTestCaseExecution")]` or `[Route("Dynamic/UpdateTestCaseExecution/{appsecret}/{appkey}")]` you can set multiple routes on your action

Comment: Can you post all of your routes?  it is likely you are hitting a route declared earlier.  such as the default route that the boilerplate code declares.

Comment: The problem had solved, it was not accessing because of protection on the partition and the IIS web server was not hitting the route, thank you guys :)